# JavaScript code doesn't work, no errors or stops

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I try to write a decoder to caesar cipher. But my code doesn't work, and there is no errors shown and it doesn't stop.

```js
let word = "привет";
let shift = 3;
let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < word.legth; i++){
    if ('А'.charCodeAt(0) <= word[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 'Я'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        let char = ((word[i].charCodeAt(0) + shift - 'А'.charCodeAt(0)) % 32) + 'А'.charCodeAt(0)
        result = result + String.fromCharCode(char);
    }
    else if ('а'.charCodeAt(0) <= word[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 'я'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        let char = ((word[i].charCodeAt(0) + shift - 'а'.charCodeAt(0)) % 32) + 'а'.charCodeAt(0)
        result = result + String.fromCharCode(char);
    }
    else {
        result = result + word[i];
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `word.legth` that looks like an error to me.

Comment: `word.legth` has a typo, it resolves to undefined, so your loop doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change word.legth to word.length

```js
let word = 'привет';
let shift = 3;
let result = '';
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if ('А'.charCodeAt(0) <= word[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 'Я'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        let char =
            ((word[i].charCodeAt(0) + shift - 'А'.charCodeAt(0)) % 32) +
            'А'.charCodeAt(0);
        result = result + String.fromCharCode(char);
    } else if (
        'а'.charCodeAt(0) <=
        word[i].charCodeAt(0) <=
        'я'.charCodeAt(0)
    ) {
        let char =
            ((word[i].charCodeAt(0) + shift - 'а'.charCodeAt(0)) % 32) +
            'а'.charCodeAt(0);
        result = result + String.fromCharCode(char);
    } else {
        result = result + word[i];
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Harry_Hopkinson Most likely because we should close questions caused by typographical errors. The goal of Stack Overflow is to help others facing the same problem. Questions caused by typographical errors are very unlikely to help others. (In that sense the answer isn't "useful", which is what votes indicate.)